# .rda file containing large list grows in size after deleting some rows

Tags: r, list, compression, rda

I had an .rda file with a large list, that looked like this:

```
[[1]] Null
[[2]] Null
...
[[1000]] (Some data)
...
```

The first `K` empty rows (999 in the example) were created because of bug in the code, so I decided to delete all the `1:K` rows. After saving the file it has grown large in size: before it was <1 GB and after it was >16GB. How could that be? How to fix it?

I can imagine that the problem is that before editing the list it had values from 1 to `N`, and after the editing it contains only values from `K+1` to `N`, but is it so different? If this is the problem, how to clear the indexing?

Comment: this is interesting, but a (small!) reproducible example (using `save()` and `file.size()`) would be very useful.

Comment: What code did you use to remove the NULLs.  Those aren't necessarily "rows" unless you had a data frame to begin with. Example of how row indexing fails `replicate(5, NULL)[3,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file might need a different compression type after removing the NULLs.  It was probably uncompressed and then recompressed under the same compression scheme although it should have been different since the list got many times smaller.

From `?save`

> ... a saved file can be uncompressed and re-compressed under a different compression scheme (and see resaveRdaFiles for a way to do so from within R).

So when I run `resaveRdaFiles` on the `z2` object in Ben Bolker's answer, it gets a good chunk smaller

```
file.info("tmp2.rda")[,1]
# [1] 2666373
tools::resaveRdaFiles("tmp2.rda")
file.info("tmp2.rda")[,1]
# [1] 2210736
```

Comment: interesting, but I'm mildly skeptical.  What does `resaveRdaFiles` do to `tmp.rda`?  The default compression is `gzip` (see `?save`), whereas `resaveRdaFiles` tries out several different compression schemes and picks the best one.

Comment: @BenBolker - size is 2212664 on tmp.rda

Answer (score 3):

I can't easily replicate this, but I offer this template: perhaps, as @RichardScriven comments above, you can tell us how you deleted the `NULL` values?

Make up data:

```
set.seed(101)
z1 <- replicate(1000,runif(1000),simplify=FALSE)
z1[1:500] <- replicate(500,NULL)
```

Save and check file size:

```
save("z1",file="tmp.rda")
file.size("tmp.rda")
## [1] 2666278
```

Keep only the last 500 elements:

```
z2 <- z1[501:1000]
save("z2",file="tmp2.rda")
file.size("tmp2.rda")
## [1] 2666249
```

Gets ever-so-slightly smaller.

Replacing `NULL` with `numeric(0)` makes the result ever-so-slightly larger.

```
z3 <- z1
z3[1:500] <- replicate(500,numeric(0))
save("z3",file="tmp3.rda")
file.size("tmp3.rda")
## [1] 2666290
```

Comment: `file.size` not found.  Forgot where it is...`utils`?

Comment: I have it in base. Could it be platform-specific? `file.info()` should work anywhere, I think.

Comment: No, on Linux there's no file.size

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to provide a reproducible example. I tried few different approaches but, like you, I was not able to produce any.

Comment: then I don't think we're going to be able to help, unless someone gets a flash of inspiration ...

Comment: You asked how did I delete `Null`'s: 
`while(is.null(data[[1]]))
  data <- data[-1]`